# Javascript - remove or set another value to URL parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a function to **enable/disable viewport** by clicking a button.

So I'm using URL parameters to add `&viewport=1` like that I can add/remove `meta name="viewport"` and reloading the page after that.

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
var $viewport = getParameterByName('viewport'),
    $url = window.location.href;
function checkViewport($btn){
    if($viewport === '1') {
        $('head meta[name=viewport]').remove();
        // here I need to change or remove the param from URL
        // tried with $url=$url.replace - not working :(
    } else if (typeof $viewport === 'undefined' || $viewport === null || $viewport === '') {
        $('head').append('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">');
        if ($url.indexOf('?') > -1){
           $url += '&viewport=1'
        } else {
           $url += '?viewport=1'
        }
    }
    window.history.replaceState(null, null, $url);
    if($btn){
        window.location.href = $url;
    }
}
```

Can anyone Help me, please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This provides the result you want for me:

```
var $url = "http://example.com?viewport=1";
console.log($url); //http://example.com?viewport=1

$url = $url.replace(/[&?]viewport=1/g, "");
console.log($url); //http://example.com
```

Comment: not working for me, is adding ?viewport=1&viewport=1

Comment: You'll have to show me what you're doing. My example works when I test it.

Comment: I believe the issue lies in the method you're trying to use for changing the address. Redirect the user to the new URL instead of trying to do the thing with window.history which isn't what you want.

Comment: fixed it in the end with your `replace` solution. thanks ;)

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help somehow. Sorry I didn't know the context better.

Comment: I know this is late, but I suggest saving the viewport option as a cookie instead of passing the data through the URL. That way you don't have to modify the history or worry about the link at all.